# Rank order row values in R while keeping NA values

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to convert values in a data frame to rank order values by row. So take this:

`df = data.frame(A = c(10, 20, NA), B = c(NA, 10, 20), C = c(20, NA, 10))`

When I do this:

`t(apply(df, 1, rank))`

I get this:

```
[1,] 1 3 2
[2,] 2 1 3
[3,] 3 2 1
```

But I want the NA values to continue showing as NA, like so:

```
[1,] 1 NA 2
[2,] 2 1 NA
[3,] NA 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the argument `na.last` and set it to `keep`:

```
t(apply(df, 1, rank, na.last='keep'))
```

Output:

```
      A  B  C
[1,]  1 NA  2
[2,]  2  1 NA
[3,] NA  2  1
```

As mentioned in the [documentation of `rank`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/rank):

> `na.last`:
> for controlling the treatment of `NA`s. If `TRUE`, missing values in the data are put last; if `FALSE`, they are put first; if `NA`, they are removed; if `"keep"` they are kept with rank `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

Here a `dplyr` approach

#### Libraries

```
library(dplyr)
```

#### Data

```
df <- tibble(A = c(10, 20, NA), B = c(NA, 10, 20), C = c(20, NA, 10))
```

#### Code

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(.fns = ~rank(x = .,na.last = "keep")))
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      A     B     C
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     NA    2
2     2     1     NA
3     NA    2     1
```